# How to boot from download mode into recovery mode

Tags: adb, samsung, recovery-mode, data-recovery, samsung-galaxy-note-8

Two days ago when I was going to use my Galaxy Note 8.0 GT-N5100 tablet I noticed it was off, but minutes before it was on and working, so I tried pressing the power button and nothing happened, plugged the charger in, nothing, no signs, it seemed bricked, so I tried to power through download mode and it worked, after that I pressed volume down to cancel it to start normally, the first samsung logo showed up (that one that says the model and stuff), but it was there for really long, i left it running and after 5 mins or so it changed to the pulsing blue samsung logo, left it there and about 30 mins later it was back to the 1st samsung logo again. I also tried a soft reset and booting to safe mode, didn't work either.

This tablet has no custom rom installed (I think it is on stock 4.4.2), the only thing different I installed is TWRP and root, years ago, but I cant boot to TWRP through the vol up+home+power, it doesnt work, tbh it never worked since back then, just like [this](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/32637/galaxy-s-gt-i9000-how-to-fix-boot-to-recovery-with-volume-uppower), the only way I found to boot to twrp was thru "adb reboot recovery" using adb, which didnt work in download mode, I want to be able to backup some data before flashing it with Odin, so here are my questions:

1- Is there any other command I could try to force it to boot to recovery?
2- Is there any way to backup data via download mode on this device?

Thank you for your attention

Answer (score 0):

If you have a device with an unlocked bootloader you can boot a recovery image without actually flashing it by running `fastboot boot <recovery.img>`, this won't persist across a reboot, AFAIK there's no fastboot pull or the like so you can't just backup via fastboot just like you would with adb, I've seen some phones even respond to `adb reboot recovery` and reboot itself to recovery but those are all stock android phones.